# Is it possible to change the value of CONSTANT(MAXPAGESIZE) in a linker script

Tags: linker, ld, binutils

I am using `ld` with a custom link script (modified from the default script used by `gcc`) and I noticed that the default value for `CONSTANT(MAXPAGESIZE)` on ARM is 64KiB. I need this value to be 4KiB.

I am aware that I can change this value on the command line by invoking

```
ld -z max-page-size=0x1000 .....
```

However I'd like to know if there is a way to change the value of the symbolic constant `MAXPAGESIZE` in the script rather than on the command-line, in order to just give the script to co-workers and not having to change their Makefiles.

At the moment, my fall-back plan is to hardcode the value by replacing `CONSTANT(MAXPAGESIZE)` with `0x1000` inside the script.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem in the meantime?

Comment: No, the only way I found is to use the command line flag. I guess I'll write a proper example and access my own answer at some point :)

Answer (score 1):

here :
    **link-ldflags += -z max-page-size=4096**